# Re-arrange deck positions in Hearthstone

Tags: hearthstone

When looking at your decks, either in the Mobile or Desktop version, is it possible to rearrange the ordering?

They appear to be listed in the order they created.
I don't want to have to keep deleting and creating decks just to bring my new ones to the front of the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no official option to order your decks.

The most used workaround for this is to open a deck and change it to wild, close it, then open it again and change back to standard. This will put the deck at the bottom of your standard decks list.

It follows the same idea as deleting and creating the decks, but slightly less complicated.

Comment: The technology just isn't there yet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move decks to any position you like, but you can move one to the bottom of the list in one of two ways:

If you have participated in a tavern brawl that included wild cards, you can do it by opening a deck, setting it to wild, closing it, and then repeating the process to set it to standard type again.

If you have not yet unlocked wild decks, you can accomplish the same thing by opening a deck, hovering near its name, clicking Copy, closing it, deleting it, creating a new deck, and answering Yes when prompted to create the deck from the clipboard (instead of picking the cards by hand).

With patience, you can use these methods to get your deck list sorted as you please.